# output contents only if timestamp is different in php

Tags: php

I have a php script that runs every minute as cronjob, gets the contents of a url in json format and output the content in realtime.

The API in json format:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": {
            "unix": 123456789        
        },
        "content": "Lorem ipsum"
    }
]
```

The PHP script:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($json);

// if timestamp is different, output the content.

echo $obj[0]->content;
```

Since the script is running every minute via cronjob, I always get the same duplicate contents every minute if timestamp hasn't changed.

I only want to output the contents if timestamp has changed so I don't get duplicate contents everytime the cronjob runs every minute.

How do I do this in php?

In other language, I have a similar issue but I solved it using the pseudo-code below:

```
declare static_time and initialize to zero;
if static_time is not equal the current_time
run the code
then set static_time again to current_time
```

But I don't know how to implement the same solution in PHP or maybe theres a better way to solve it in PHP without using a database.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I understand you are using a database. so why don't you use a unique column as a key, then you could first check if you have the timestamp already in the database ...

Comment: @MaxMuster I dont have a database. thats easy if using a database but in this case, the script does not have a database.

Comment: do you have write rights in some folder ?